# How to pass an array of vectors in pyOpenCL

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I'm moving a simulation into pyOpenCL and can't get my data access to work. I'm trying to supply a 1D array of vectors (well, actually several, but the example I've included just used one).

Currently, several vectors are copied over just fine, but then the data is simply not what I supplied.

I don't think I've posted here before, so apologies if any of the formatting/presentation is wrong. Also, I've just stripped out all the simulation code, so I realise this code is currently not actually doing anything, I just want to get the buffer passing correct.

Thanks in advance.

The kernel (kertest.py):

```
step1 = """
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_printf: enable
#define X xdim
#define Y ydim
__kernel void k1(__global float3 *spins,
                 __local float3 *tile)
{        
    ushort lid = 2 * get_local_id(0);
    ushort group = 2 * get_group_id(0);
    ushort num = get_num_groups(0);
    int lim = X*Y*3;

    for (ushort i = 0; i < lim; i++)
        {
            if (lid == 0 && group == 0)
            {
                printf("%f :: %d\\n", spins[i].x, i);
            }
         }
}"""
```

The code itself (gputest.py):

```
import kertest as k2D
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl

class GPU_MC2DSim():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        if x >= y:
            self.xdim = int(self.x)
            self.ydim = int(self.y)
        else:
            self.xdim = int(self.y)
            self.ydim = int(self.x)

        if self.xdim % 2 != 0: self.xdim += 1

        if self.ydim % 2 != 0: self.ydim += 1

        self.M = np.ones((self.xdim*self.ydim, 3)).astype(np.float32)
        self.M[:, 1] += 1.0
        self.M[:, 2] += 2.0

        print self.M

    def simulate(self):
        ctx = cl.create_some_context()
        q = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
        mf = cl.mem_flags

        #Pass buffer:
        M_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_WRITE | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf = self.M)

        #Insert kernel parameters:
        params = {"xdim" : "%d" % (self.xdim),
                  "ydim" : "%d" % (self.ydim),
                  }
        for name in params:
            k2D.step1 = k2D.step1.replace(name, params[name])

        #Compile kernel:
        step1 = cl.Program(ctx, k2D.step1).build()

        locmem = cl.LocalMemory(self.xdim*4*4)

        step1.k1(q, ((self.xdim*self.ydim)/4,), (self.xdim/2,), M_buf, locmem).wait()
        return None

xdim = 4
ydim = 4
sim = GPU_MC2DSim(xdim, ydim)
sim.simulate()
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code for copying the data to the device is just fine. However, your kernel has at least two problems:

1. `float3` values are expected to be 16-byte aligned, as per OpenCL 1.2 Spec, 6.1.5:

   > For 3-component vector data types, the size of the data type is 4 * `sizeof`(component). This means that a 3-component vector data type will be aligned to a 4 * `sizeof`(component) boundary.  The **vload3** and **vstore3** built-in functions can be used to read and write, respectively, 3-component vector data types from an array of packed scalar data type.

   The values you upload to the devices are not properly aligned for the kernel to read `float3` values directly.
2. Your limit calculation `int lim = X*Y*3;` is slightly off. You are already trying to read from an array of `float3`, so the `*3` is superfluous.

The solution to both problems is simple: as stated in the spec, you should use **vload3** to load from an array of `float`s:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_printf: enable
#define X xdim
#define Y ydim
__kernel void k1(__global float *spins,
                 __local float3 *tile)
{
    ushort lid = 2 * get_local_id(0);
    ushort group = 2 * get_group_id(0);
    ushort num = get_num_groups(0);
    int lim = X*Y;

    for (ushort i = 0; i < lim; i++)
        {
            if (lid == 0 && group == 0)
            {
                float3 vec = vload3(i, spins);
                printf("(%f, %f, %f) :: %d\\n", vec.x, vec.y, vec.z, i);
            }
         }
}
```